# pandas joins 2 dataframes when one df is created from a groupby result of a third df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to join 2 `df`, `A` and `B`, where `B` is generated based on a `groupby` of another `df`, i.e. `C`,

```
B = pd.DataFrame(C.groupby('object_id').apply(
lambda x: x[['number', 'date', 'user_id', 'change']].to_dict('records')))

B.columns = ['change_history']

B['num_changes'] = B['change_history'].apply(lambda x: len(x))

# reset index to default integer index to get object_id for B
B = B.reset_index()
data = A.merge(B, how='left', on='object_id')
```

I am wondering is there a better way to do it in terms of memory usage and time efficiency.

```
df C
object_id     number          date       user_id     change
1000001       1234          2017-01-01   ABC         6666661111
1000001       04447         2018-01-01   ABC         9999990000
1000002       <AAA>0000001  2018-02-02   DEF         3333339999
1000002       <AAA>0999999  2018-03-03   DEF         4444448888
1000003       980000        2018-04-05   DEF         5555550000
1000004       970000        2018-05-06   XYZ         3200000000

df A
object_id    name    
1000001      company_a
1000001      company_a
1000002      company_b
1000002      company_b
1000003      company_c
1000004      company_d
```

Comment: can you show us the sample data ?

Comment: @Wen I have modified my op and added some samples.

Comment: `B['num_changes'] = B['change_history'].str.len()` at least here we do not need apply

Comment: When i use the code and data you posted i end up with lists of dicts in one column. Are you sure thats what you want? If thats the case i don't think theres a more efficient way to do it because normally you don't do something like that in pandas.

Comment: @P.Tillmann yea, it is desired result, what do you suggest then?